# Stuck on Splash Screen with React-Native 0.55.4 and Expo 28.0.0

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I just release an App to PlayStore, and some user stuck on Splash Screen (not depend on any OS version).
The old version use OTA update of Expo, I think that the reason why they stuck on Splash screen; So, the new version I just disable OTA update and it still stuck on it.
I tried to remove all app data, then uninstall the app, install the app again then it works normally (it stills randomly works).

So, how can I fix this issue? I can't ask every user to clear their app data manually then install the app again.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you do when your app is starting? Are you waiting for any fonts or other data to load? Do you use <AppLoading> while this is done?

Comment: I don't use AppLoading.
There is no request on app boot, just render the Login view.
But it stills not render.

Comment: I see... Can you post your app.json and App.js files?

Comment: Show some code!!!!

Comment: My app.json: https://pastebin.com/mHUk9SAU

Comment: My App.js: https://pastebin.com/5YEUF9fT

Comment: What is 'googleServicesFile' referred to in app.json? I am not familiar with it.
But the most relevant thing is the handling of isAppReady. I also don't have an idea what all the BaseContext.xxx are doing...

Comment: what is this BaseContext?? i can not find any documentation on it even!

Comment: That's my React Context file.
It does nothing except set init state.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your `BaseContext._defaultValue` maybe if you can show how you are making it. also try `Async await` in `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

delete the .expo folder on your project

run npm install

npm start